# Desktop Streaming(Raspberry pi Live Desktop & Audio Streaming to the browser with WebRTC)

Tags: raspberry-pi, streaming, webrtc, desktop, uv4l

I wanted to load the xscreen driver. so I opened a terminal and typed the following commands:

```
$uv4l --driver xscreen --auto-video_nr --display :0 --framerate 10 --server-option '--port=5678'
```

This is the normal result:

```
 raspberrypi ~ $ uv4l --driver xscreen --auto-video_nr --display :0 --framerate 10 --server-option '--port=5678'

 [core] Trying driver 'xscreen' from built-in drivers...
 [core] Driver 'xscreen' not found
 [core] Trying driver 'xscreen' from external plug-in's...
 [driver] Opening display: :0
 [driver] Display open, screen 0: 640x480, depth: 24, bpp: 32, big endian: false
 [driver] Specified capturing rectangle: (xorigin 0, yorigin 0, width 640, height 480)
 [core] Device detected!
 [core] Trying to load the the Streaming Server plug-in...
 [server] HTTP Streaming & WebRTC Signalling Server v1.1.18 built on Apr 22 2015
 [core] Streaming Server loaded!
 [core] Cannot create /dev/video0 because file already exists
 [core] Registering device node /dev/video1
 [server] Web Streaming Server listening on port 9000
```

But I got this message:

```
 pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uv4l --driver xscreen --auto-video_nr --display :0 --framerate 10 --server-option '--port=5678'
 <notice> [core] Trying driver 'xscreen' from built-in drivers...
 <warning> [core] Driver 'xscreen' not found
 <notice> [core] Trying driver 'xscreen' from external plug-in's...
 <notice> [driver] Opening display: :0
 <notice> [driver] Display open, screen 0: 640x480, depth: 24, bpp: 32, big endian: false
 <notice> [driver] Specified capturing rectangle: (xorigin 0, yorigin 0, width 640, height 480)
 <notice> [core] Device detected!
 <warning> [core] Cannot create /dev/video0 because file already exists
 <warning> [core] Cannot create /dev/video1 because file already exists
 <notice> [core] Registering device node /dev/video2
```

My result do not have this part:

```
 [server] HTTP Streaming & WebRTC Signalling Server v1.1.18 built on Apr 22 2015
 [core] Streaming Server loaded!
```

What is my problem? Please help me!

Comment: Did you install all [requirements](https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/tutorials/desktop-streaming)?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.